# rescue any ActiveRecordError on superclass

Tags: ruby

I'm workig with sidekiq and I have this class

```
class APIWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker

  def message(text)
    store message: text
  end
end
```

my workers are like this

```
class GenericWorker < APIWorker
  def perform(something)
   # do some hard work 
  end
end
```

what I want to do is to catch any `ActiveRecordError`on my workers, but I want to catch them on `APIWorker` instead all workers that inherit `APIWorker` doing some sort of DRY.
I don't know if this is possible and any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about defining a `perform` method in `APIWorker` class as well, and than rescuing in `APIWorker` so each class which inherits this and `perform`, this will be taken care of.

```rb
class GenericWorker < APIWorker
  def perform(something)
   super do
     # do some hard work       
   end
  end
end


class APIWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker

  def message(text)
    store message: text
  end

  def perform
    begin
      yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
      #Your rescue code here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I used this `super { .. }` style a lot in our code base.. I like this technique... +1

Comment: I'm trying this code right now and I'm seeing `uninitialized constant APIWorker::ActiveRecordError`. What is missing?

Comment: @saurabh might want to fix his/her answer too

Comment: @caarlos0: Thanks for taking care of it, was busy yesterday, Thanks.